# Minimize linear objective subject to unit norm constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, qclp

I have a linear function with unit norm constraint that I need to minimize.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{w}{\text{minimize}} & w^\top x\\ \text{subject to} & \|w\| = 1 \end{array}$$

Is there a way to do this analytically?

My current thinking is that:

$$ \frac{d}{d w} w^\top x = x $$

$$ w = \|x\| $$

But this doesn't seem to make sense at all.

Thanks

Comment: see [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Comment: What kind of norm is $\|\cdot\|$? In general, the best "analytical" expression you can get is "minus the [dual norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm#Mathematical_Optimization) of $x$".

Answer (score 4):

Taking the lagrangian we have equivalently

$$
L(w,\lambda) = w^\top x + \lambda (w^\top w -1)
$$

and the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \cases{x+2\lambda w = 0\\ w^\top w - 1 = 0}
$$

As $w = -\frac{1}{2\lambda}x$ we have

$$
\frac{1}{4\lambda^2}x^\top x = 1
$$

or

$$
\lambda = \pm\frac 12||x||
$$

and finally

$$
w = \pm \frac{x}{||x||}
$$

Comment: I think you should mention that the negative solution minimizes the objective, while the positive solution maximizes it.

Answer (score 1):

Good thinking, incorrect calculation.  Instead of doing this "matricially", do it using the dot product: $w \cdot x$ is maximized for that $w$, of unit magnitude, which points in the direction of $x$.  Therefore, $w$ must be co-directional with $x$ and must have unit magnitude; i.e.,
$$
w = {1 \over || x ||} x.
$$
Your attempt at a gradient calculation is incorrect because it ignores the constraint that $w$ must lie on the unit sphere.  Here is a way to do it.  If $w(t)$ is a smooth curve on that sphere parametrized by $t$, however, and if the maximum of $w(t) \cdot x$ is attained at some $t^*$, then:
$$
0 = {d \over dt}|_{t = t^*} ( w(t) \cdot x ) = w'(t^*) \cdot x,
$$ 
which means $w'(t^*)$ must be orthogonal to $x$.  We see that $x$ is normal to the hyperplane that is tangent to the unit sphere at $w(t^*)$, which means that $w(t^*)$ is co-directional with $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still working on this but I've found this solution maximises my cost function. Is there another way to constrain it to the unit sphere?

Comment: min f(x) = - max [- f(x) ] :)